# limit of summation $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{n^2+1}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this limit. I tried to separate the sums into $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{n^2}{2^n}$ which  equals to 0 and $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2^n}$ which also equals 0, but that seems to be wrong since the answer I'm getting from wolfarm equals to 7.

Comment: You can't have $n$ appear both in the limit and as the sumation index! The expression $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is non-sensical, because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is **independent** of $n$.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{N\to +\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N$?

Comment: Please explain us how you can find that the limit of $1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16+...$ is zero (You are summing positive terms). Before thinking of deriving the good value of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (n^2+1)/2^n$, you must try to get the good value of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 1/2^n$.

Comment: I was  calculation those limits at infinity which is wrong since I have to calculate the limit of summation I understood what I did wrong there but still have no idea how to find the values you mentioned, I found 2 formulas provided in one of the answers but I don't know where they come from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the sum of an infinite geometric series with common ratio $|r| < 1$ is $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term in the series.
Here is an elementary proof for the sum $\sum_{k = 11}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2^k}$. Let $S$ be the sum
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{4} + \frac{9}{8} + \frac{16}{16} + \ldots\\
\frac{S}{2} &= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4}{8} + \frac{9}{16} + \frac{16}{24} + \ldots\\
S - \frac{S}{2} &= \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{4}{4} - \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{9}{8} - \frac{4}{8}) + (\frac{16}{16} - \frac{9}{16}) + \ldots\\
\frac{S}{2} &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{5}{8} + \frac{7}{16} + \ldots
\end{align}
Now you can stop here if you know the limit of an arithmetico-geometric series, but we can continue to reduce this to a geometric series.
\begin{align}
\frac{S}{2} &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{5}{8} + \frac{7}{16} + \ldots\\
\frac{S}{4} &= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{5}{16} + \frac{7}{32} + \ldots\\
\frac{S}{2} - \frac{S}{4} &= \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{5}{8} - \frac{3}{8}) + (\frac{7}{16} - \frac{5}{16}) + \ldots\\
\frac{S}{4} &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{2}{8} + \frac{2}{16} + \ldots\\
\frac{S}{4} &= \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \ldots)
\end{align}
The series in the bracket is an infinite geometric series so
\begin{align}
\frac{S}{4} &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2} + 1 = \frac{3}{2}\\
S &= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 6
\end{align}
The result can now be used to solve the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{n^2 + 1}{2^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 6 + \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 6 + 1 = 7.
\end{align}
This method only requires pre-calculus level algebra.

Comment: This is actually a very simple method which helped me in other similar tasks, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
S_x &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{n^2}{2^n}\\
&= 2S_x - S_x\\
&= 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{n^2}{2^n} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{n^2}{2^n}\\
&= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{x-1} \frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{n^2}{2^n}\\
&= \frac{1}{2^0}  + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x-1} \frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x-1} \frac{n^2}{2^n} - \frac{x^2}{2^x}\\
&= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2^x} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x-1} \frac{2n+1}{2^n}\\
&= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2^x} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x-1} \frac{2n}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{1}{2^n}\\
&= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2^x} + 2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x-1} \frac{n}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{2^n}\\
&= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2^x} + 2\cdot \frac{2^x-(x-1)-2}{2^{x-1}} + \frac{2^{x-1}-1}{2^{x-1}}\\
&= \frac{3\cdot 2^{x+1}-x^2-4 x-6}{2^x}
\end{align}
and
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{2^x-1}{2^x}$$
so
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{n^2 + 1}{2^n} &= \frac{3\cdot 2^{x+1}-x^2-4 x-6}{2^x} + \frac{2^x-1}{2^x}\\
&= \frac{3\cdot 2^{x+1}-x^2-4 x-6+2^x-1}{2^x}\\
&= \frac{3\cdot 2^{x+1}+2^x-x^2-4 x-6-1}{2^x}
\end{align}
thus
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x} \frac{n^2 + 1}{2^n} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3\cdot 2^{x+1}+2^x-x^2-4 x-6-1}{2^x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} 3\cdot 2 + 1 + \frac{-x^2-4 x-6-1}{2^x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} 6 + 1 + 0\\
&= 7
\end{align}

Comment: How did you derive the first two formula? What is $x$? An integer?

Comment: added proof to formulas!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider $$A=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (n^2+1){x^n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (n(n-1)+n+1){x^n}$$ $$A=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n-1)x^n+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$$ $$A=x^2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n-1)x^{n-2}+x\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$$ in which you recognize the second and first derivatives of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$; you know what is this sum equals to. complete and simplify. When finished, set $x=\frac 12$.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to continue solving the problem , I'd be glad if you could explain a bit more.

Comment: What is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$ equal to ?

Comment: sum of a geometric series , everything's clear now thank you.

Comment: @BehrangBehvandi. You are welcome ! Now, you can use it for other values of $x$, I bet.

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't received more up votes.  +1 from me. - Mark